# Change FetchType.LAZY to FetchType.EAGER temporary at runtime (Hibernate/JPA)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have entity with some fields marked as `LAZY`. In order to load  `LAZY` fields one must just access a getter while session is opened so ORM proxy perform `select` sub-queries.

But this is suboptimal in case when you need a fully resolved object, using the same strategy as "eager" relations fetched by `join`.

How is it possible to mark some fields as `EAGER` temporary only for one query?

Is that possible with JPA standard or does it require proprietary extension like Hibernate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring `JpaRepository` allows marking queries (including custom) with `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph`:

```
@Entity Book {
     @Id Long id;
     @OneToMany List<Author> authors;
}

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"authors", "author.address"})
@Query("select b from Book b" +
        " where b.id in (:ids)")
List<Book> loadAll(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

Answer (score 9):

Hibernate has a feature called [Fetch Profiles](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-profiles) that solves this problem. It requires access to Hibernate `Session`, but you can use `unwrap()` to access it from `EntityManager`.

If you want a pure JPA solution, you can use queries with `join fetch` when loading objects in use cases that require eager fetching.

**UPDATE:**
JPA 2.1 (implemented by Hibernate 4.3) supports a feature similar to fetch profiles - [entity graphs](http://hantsy.blogspot.ru/2013/12/jpa-21-entity-graph.html).

Comment: I am trying to fetch 10 lists using entity graph and join fetch but in both case, i am getting org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags. Is there any workaround for these types of scenarios ?

Comment: Avoid using Join Fetch more than one time otherwise it will lead to MultipleBagFetchException..Use one join fetch to get one child list and using this result create another join fetch to get another child list

Answer (score 1):

Due to fetch = FetchType.LAZY at the associated collection Faced problem like `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: could not initialize proxy-no session`

Now changing `fetch = FetchType.LAZY to fetch = FetchType.EGAR` is the worst solution as it opens to some other regerations

Then i thought what if there is a way to make fetch type lazy to egar at runtime for some operations...

Then i tried to understand the problem like why i faced LazyInitializationException

SO i realized that this problems occurs because we are doing db operation after the session is closed so we have to make all db operations within the session

So the solution is to wrap the method which has as db operation performed within a **Transaction** .
Check below code snippet-->

```
 @Transactional
    public void fetchThroughLazy() {

        List<UserEntity> userList = aeqplUserRepository.findByEmailEndingWith("@amazon.com");
        userList.forEach(user->{
            logger.info("user --->{}",user);
            logger.info("user permission--->{}",user.getPermissions());
        });
    }
```

But again this is not a good solution because it will lead to Hibernate N+1 problem

**Best Solution**---> Either Use **EntityGraph or Join Fetch**

Check Below code snippet --->>

```
public void fetchThroughJPQLJoinFetch() {

            List<UserEntity> userList = entityManager.createQuery("select distinct u from UserEntity u left join fetch u.permissions Where u.email like :endsWith",UserEntity.class)
            .setParameter("endsWith", "%@google.com")
            .setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
            .getResultList();
        userList.forEach(user->{
            logger.info("user --->{}",user);
            logger.info("user permission--->{}",user.getPermissions());
        });
        
    }
    
    public void fetchThroughJPQLEntityGraph() {
        EntityGraph<UserEntity> userEntityGraph = em.createEntityGraph(UserEntity.class);
        userEntityGraph.addSubgraph("permissions");
        
        List<UserEntity> userList = em.createQuery("Select u From UserEntity u Where u.email Like :endsWith",UserEntity.class)
            .setParameter("endsWith", "%@facebook.com")
            .setHint(QueryHints.LOADGRAPH, userEntityGraph)
            .getResultList();
        userList.forEach(user->{
            logger.info("user --->{}",user);
            logger.info("user permission--->{}",user.getPermissions());
        });
    }


@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userEntity",cascade = CascadeType.All,fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<PermissionEntity> cmList =new ArrayList<>();

    //setters and getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="permission")
public class PermissionEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserEntity userEntity;

    //setters and getters
}
```

**Note**-> Avoid using **Join Fetch** more Than once otherwise it will throw **MultipleBagFetchException**