# LazyInitializationException: How do I offload a DB-intensive process to an Executor and still have transactional support with Hibernate?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, spring-data

### What I have

I have a working web app that has an endpoint to search for items. The middle tier's `search` method looks something like this:

```
private ListingScoringFunction scoringFunc;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<Listing> search(ListingSearchParameters params) {
  Page<Long> pageOfListingIds = listingSearchRepo.searchForListingIds(params);
  return pageOfListingIds.map(eachListingId -> {
    var eachEntity = listingRepo.getOne(eachListingId).get();
    var score = scoringFunc.score(eachEntity);
    // Map the Hibernate entity to a serializable DTO
    return ModelMappings.toListing(eachEntity, score);
  });
}
```

When I call `ModelMappings.toListing()`, I access a bunch of lazy-loaded fields. Currently, this works because all the operations are encapsulated in an active session/transaction.

### What I want

Because of the lazy-loaded properties, I make quite a few trips to the database. I don't want to change those fields to be eagerly-loaded, due to other constraints in the system. I want to increase throughput by multi-threading: while one thread is waiting for DB I/O, transfer execution to a thread that is ready to run the scoring function.

I created an `ExecutorService` with a fixed thread pool, wired it into my Service, and modified the code to look like this:

```
private ListingScoringFunction scoringFunc;
private ExecutorService scoringExecutor;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<Listing> search(ListingSearchParameters params) {
  Page<Long> pageOfListingIds = listingSearchRepo.searchForListingIds(params);
  List<Listing> scoredListings = scoreListingsById(pageOfListingIds);
  return new PageImpl<>(scoredListings);
}

private List<Listing> scoreListingsById(Page<Long> listingIds) {
  List<Listing> scoredListings;
  List<CompletableFuture<Listing>> resultList = listingIds.stream()
    .map(eachListingId -> {
        Supplier<Listing> scoreTask = () -> this.convertToScoredListing(eachListingId);
        return scoreTask;
     })
     .map(each -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(each, scoringExecutor))
     .toList();
  CompletableFuture.allOf(resultList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
  scoredListings = resultList.stream()
    .map(eachFuture -> eachFuture.getNow(null))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .toList();
  return scoredListings;
}

@Transactional
public Listing convertToScoredListing(Long eachListingId) {
  var eachListing = listingRepo.findById(eachListingId).get();
  var score = scoringFunc.score(eachListing);
  Listing scoredListing = ModelMappings.toListing(eachListing, score);
  return scoredListing;
}
```

### What's going wrong

When I run this new code and try to access the lazy-loaded field from within the thread pool, I get the dreaded "no Session" error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of ___, 
  could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

As I understand it, this usually means that I invoked code in such a way that Spring/Hibernate couldn't tell that I'd crossed a transactional boundary (defined by the `@Transactional` annotation). What is odd is that the `findById()` call succeeds, but the subsequent `ListingEntity.getLazyLoadedField()` call is the one that fails and throws the exception. I turned up some of the Hibernate logging and saw that it begins a transaction for the `listingRepo.findById()` call, but then immediately commits it, so that by the time I'm accessing lazy fields, the transaction is committed and the session is closed. I interpret this to mean that when I call the `@Repository` instance, Hibernate can tell that this is a transactional boundary that has been crossed. What I don't understand is that in my `Supplier` that I submit to the `ExecutorService`, I call `convertToScoredListing()`, which is annotated with `@Transactional`. I don't understand why that's not enough to have a session for the entire method's execution.

Possible messy solutions, that I'd like to avoid:

- Move `convertToScoredListing()` to another class, to make it more obvious that a boundary has been crossed. Seems messy to force a method out of a class when it's very tightly coupled to that class.
- Manually manage Sessions/transactions in the thread.
- Start the session in the view/presentation layer.

What's the correct configuration for offloading DB-accessing code to a thread? How do I get Hibernate to run my thread in a Session?

Comment: If you don't want to change the fetchtype for all existing code and can do it for this scenario [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717865/change-fetchtype-lazy-to-fetchtype-eager-temporary-at-runtime-hibernate-jpa) could be helpful where we are changing fetchtype at runtime

Comment: Also transaction in lambda will not work as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60651339/transactional-in-lambda-expressions).In your case 'scoreTask' is variable declaration

Comment: DB I/O calls in JPA are blocking calls [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294522/jpa-repositories-and-blocking-i-o) so the approach -if a thread is waiting for dbResult it should rather call scorefunc is incorrect.Ofcourse  DB calls could be parallelize as DB could handle multiple concurrent connections.

Comment: Thanks, @Sagar, these were useful resources. If I have more time to come back to this, I'd like to try the `@EntityGraph` approach.

Comment: `@Transactional` does not work when a class is self-invoking. You can inject the class to itself and invoke it that way, that should preserve the transactional context.


> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation [...] does not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional 

[source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/annotations.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your first approach has `n+1` [issue](https://vladmihalcea.com/n-plus-1-query-problem/) because you're querying `getOne` or `findById` inside loop. If you turn on `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and count the number of queries, it's going to be `pageSize + 1` (and another 1 for `counting page`). This is the root cause of the problem.

There are several ways to solve it, but the simplest I can see in your post is, instead of using methods `getOne` or `findById` create this method in `Repository`

```
List<ListingEntity> findByIdIn(Collection<Long> ids);
```

Then apply it to service

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<Listing> search(ListingSearchParameters params) {
  Page<Long> pageOfListingIds = listingSearchRepo.searchForListingIds(params);
  List<ListingEntity> listingEntities = repo.findByIdIn(pageOfListingIds.getContent());
  List<Listing> listings = convertToScoredListings(listingEntities);
  return new PageImpl<>(listings, pageable, pageOfListingIds.getTotalElements());
}

@Transactional
public Listing convertToScoredListings(List<ListingEntity> listingEntities) {
  return listingEntities.stream()
    .map(entity -> {
       var score = scoringFunc.score(eachListing);
       return ModelMappings.toListing(eachListing, score);
    })
    .collect(toList());
}
```

Now you can check it, there're only 3 queries generated by Hibernate (select ids, select count, select listingEntities by ids)

The second part of post is interesting, multi-threads to improve performance. Yeah could be, but it's going to be helpful when we apply for writing data instead of reading like this (only 3 queries).

Comment: I originally used the `findAllById()` call that's provided by `CrudRepository`, but strangely it performed much worse than doing a `findById()` in a loop, which is why I moved away from using it.

Comment: Can u provide the logs to prove that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using a `TransactionTemplate` in my `ExecutorService` to create sessions whenever a thread was run asynchronously. The basic strategy was to create my own `ExecutorService` subclass that simply wrapped the submitted tasks in a transaction:

```
public class TransactionalExecutorService implements ExecutorService {
  private final ExecutorService internalExecutor;
  private final TransactionTemplate txnTemplate;

  public TransactionalExecutorService(
      int threadCount,
      PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager
  ) {
    internalExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
    txnTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
  }

  private Runnable wrapInTransaction(Runnable threadWork) {
    return () -> txnTemplate.execute((txnStatus) -> {
      threadWork.run();
      return null;
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void execute(Runnable command) {
    internalExecutor.execute(wrapInTransaction(command));
  }

  /* ...similar implementations for submit/invoke methods */
}
```

It works, but it still feels like I'm missing something that the framework would already provide, or misunderstanding a concept.